# How to present employee attendance in tabular form

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a table which stores the attendance of the employees through a hand punch machine . It works as first in last out logic and shows the attendance of the emmploye.

Now I want to prepare the whole department employees attendance sheet month wise in total days

The tabular form which is proposed by the management is

```
Employee Name  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |6 |..... so on to the days in a month 
John Carpenter | P | P | A | A | P | LFP
John Seraph A  | P | P | A | A | P | LFP
```

We have SQL Server 2000 at the back end and front end is developed on C# . We will be using crystal reports.

Table Structure :

tbl_Attendance
tbl_department
tbl_employee
tbl_employeeShifts
tbl_leaves
tbl_shifts

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Attendance] (
    [AttendanceID] [bigint] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [PNO] [bigint] NULL ,
    [AttDate] [datetime] NULL ,
    [CurrentShift] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [ReaderID] [bigint] NULL ,
    [Status] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [flag] [char] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [ManualFlag] [char] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Department] (
    [DeptID] [bigint] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [DeptName] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Employee] (
    [EmpID] [bigint] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [PNO] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [T1] [char] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [T2] [char] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [T3] [char] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [T4] [char] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [T5] [char] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [T6] [char] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [T7] [char] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [T8] [char] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [T9] [char] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL ,
    [EmpName] [varchar] (100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [Type] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_EmployeeShifts] (
    [EmpShiftID] [bigint] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [EmpID] [bigint] NULL ,
    [ShiftID] [bigint] NULL ,
    [DateFrom] [datetime] NULL ,
    [DateTo] [datetime] NULL ,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL ,
    [DeptID] [bigint] NULL ,
    [flag] [bit] NULL ,
    [uFlag] [char] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_LoginTime] (
    [LoginTimeID] [bigint] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [UserID] [bigint] NULL ,
    [LoginTime] [datetime] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Permission] (
    [EmpPermissionID] [bigint] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [EmpID] [bigint] NULL ,
    [DateFrom] [datetime] NULL ,
    [DateTo] [datetime] NULL ,
    [Type] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL ,
    [flag] [char] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Shifts] (
    [ShiftID] [bigint] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [StartShift] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [EndShift] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL ,
    [GraceTime] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [ShiftType] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_UserInfo] (
    [UserID] [bigint] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [UserName] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [UserPassword] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Above is the table structure . All I want to do some joins and get the report in this format .

as mentioned above

A little help in the query logic would be appreciated.

Comment: This is way too broad. Have a look at SQL server PIVOT functionality here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx... and maybe come back when you have more specific questions or problems.

Comment: I cannot see what is the problem with this question and why it is downvoted so many times. For me it looks like a normal question. The only option here is to create SQL , which will return data in a format : EmployeeName, Day, Value.Value should be int (0 - non presented, 1 presented). In Crystal use a crosstab and put EmployeeName in the row section, Day in the column section and Value in the Details section. This will create the presentation you want, the only difference will be that you will see 0/1 instead of P/A. String cannot be summarized in Crystal reports crosstab.

Comment: SQL Pivot is not an option because will create a table with different number of columns (for different months). Crystal reports, which is one of the requirements, will be not able to present this correctly.

Comment: I have reedited the post with the table structure . Let me know if its possible to get the desired outcome design with the mentioned table structure

Answer (score 0):

you can use cross-tab report which is used for tabular format.

[Attandance report creation with cross-tab](http://forums.asp.net/t/1926989.aspx?Cross%20Tab%20Report)

[cross-tab example](http://reportsyouneed.com/understanding-crystal-cross-tabs-part-1/)

[Cross-tab exmple2](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-32376)